# Tamaño error, alguien sabe como recuperar un proyecto eliminado por error en Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, projectserver

Tamaño error. Di click derecho eliminar al proyecto pero elimino el proyecto en el disco duro tambien

Alguien sabe como recuperar un proyecto eliminado por error en Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si seleccionaste la opción:

> Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)

No puede ser recuperado ya que lo eliminaste del disco. Puedes realizar algunas opciones como son :

http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download/portable

http://diskdigger.org/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17119/windows-7-recover-lost-deleted-files

http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/deleted-recovery-software/free-undelete-tool-program.htm

http://pcinspector.de/

Pero sin tener la seguridad de recuperar los archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no seleccionaste esta opción lo puedes buscar y abrir nuevamente para agregarlo a tu workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Si eliminaste con opción de borrar los datos en el disco duro, depende de tu sistema operativo. En la mayoría de los casos, "borrar" no necesariamente significa que los datos estan perdidos, recuperación del papelero hasta heramientas de recuperación de archivos borrados como [esto por ejemplo](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/deleted-recovery-software/free-undelete-tool-program.htm) pueden salvar los datos.

Si te resulta de recuperar los datos, puedes despues importar el proyecto de nuevo en eclipse.